# Помогите php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть php скрипт, он создает новую строку с данными в базе данных, но id новых строк 0. Не могу разобраться почему?

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `snonli`.`user` (`last_name`, `first_name`,`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$lastname', '$firstname', '$email', '$password');");
```

Comment: Покажите сам скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно при создании таблицы не стоит A_I

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я пытаюсь поставить, но мне выдает: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Экспортируй таблицу и скинь

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/uTBxOHMS3VjmrM

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/VWQSOfeS3VjoJ7  Должно работать

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо)